# What do the special brackets (| ... |) desugar into?

Tags: haskell, syntax, arrows

I've read the [arrow notation documentation page](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/arrow-notation.html), but it's not entirely clear to me what the "pipe brackets" used under "7.10.3. Defining your own control structures" desugar into.

Given the example in the above document

```
proc x -> do
    y <- f -< x+1
    (|untilA (increment -< x+y) (within 0.5 -< x)|)
```

What's the equivalent code without using arrow notation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `(| ... |)` brackets (usually called banana brackets) are for applying a function that operates on commands, inside **proc** notation. They are used to disambiguate a function that operates on commands (called an 'operator') from a normal command. Binary infix operators are special cased, so you don't need to write `(| (&&&) x y |)`.

As for the desugaring, they're GHC's version of the **form** keyword from [the Arrows paper](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/notation.pdf).

**form** is defined as follows:

> **proc** p -> **form** *e* c1 c2 ... cn
>
> =
>
> *e* (**proc** p -> c1) (**proc** p -> c2) ... (**proc** p -> cn)

So, `proc x -> (|untilA (increment -< x+y) (within 0.5 -< x)|)` would become:

```
untilA (proc x -> increment -< x+y) (proc x -> within 0.5 -< x)
```

If you want to desugar this entirely so there is no arrow syntax left, it would become:

```
untilA (arr (\x -> x+y) >>> increment) (arr (\x -> x) >>> within 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very rough and intuitive answer and I'm not certain it's correct but it feels like it is.  If you have

```
proc a -> do
    a1 <- command1 <- ...
    ...
    an <- commandn <- ...

    (| structure (block1 -< expression1[a, a1, ..., an])
                 ...
                 (blockm -< expressionm[a, a1, ..., an])
    |)
```

then `(|` `|)` is a way of feeding in all the `<-`-bound variables in scope into the `block`s, i.e. it becomes (equivalent to)

```
proc a -> do
    a1 <- command1 <- ...
    ...
    an <- commandn <- ...

    structure (proc (a, a1, ..., an) -> do
                   block1 -< expression1[a, a1, ..., an])
              ...
              (proc (a, a1, ..., an) -> do
                   blockm -< expressionm[a, a1, ..., an])
                       -< (a, a1, ..., an)
```

I only grasped this when reading Oliver Charles's docs for [antijoins in Rel8](https://rel8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#antijoins).  I still find it rather mind-bending.

Comment: And I think that the variables captured by `-<` in the arguments to the operation (`structure`) are forced to be related to the variables bound outside the operation by `<-` by requiring that the arrow arguments to `structure` are polymorphic in their input type.